# How to upload files encrypted using "cipher" to onedrive so that they are not decrypted

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-explorer, encryption, onedrive

I am encrypting files using windows built in command line tool called cipher. When I copy the encrypted file from a usb to another pc it is encrypted and its not accessed on another pc. But if I sync those files from the same pc they were encrypted on, I am getting decrypted copies of the files on onedrive. Those files are windows backup files and I don't want to delete the certificate/keys from the policy manager so that windows can have uninterrupted access to those files while onedrive uploads encrypted copies of them.

Answer (score 2):

EFS (as used by `cipher`) is supposed to be entirely transparent to programs. So when you copy it to an external HD, the OS actually *decrypts* data first, and encrypts again when writing to the new disk. You aren't just copying around an encrypted bundle as the case would be with PGP or ZIP.

It *is* possible to obtain the encrypted version of these files, but I don't think Windows has a built-in command for that, only an API meant for use by third-party backup software.

The API in question is [OpenEncryptedFileRaw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365429(v=vs.85).aspx) and related functions. I'm not sure what tools make use of it. It seems Bareos or [grke/burp](https://github.com/grke/burp) might do that.

(I had once [written my own](https://github.com/grawity/vssbackup) program for that – see `efs.cs` and `efs-backup.cs` – but I don't even remember how to compile it anymore. Maybe someone else will find the source code useful though.)

Such tools are only usable by administrators or if you assign yourself SeBackupPrivilege.